# css - does there exist a way to style width and height in the same line?

Tags: css

I was thinking about how to make my css code shorter and was wondering if there was a trick to defining both width and height in the same line? Kind of like how margin = margin-top,right,bottom,left. Is there something like dimension: width height;??

Comment: BoltClock is completely right, there is none. A list & description of all available css shorthands is given here: http://www.dustindiaz.com/css-shorthand/

Answer (score 5):

No, there isn't such a `dimension` property. (Now that you mention it, I think it'd be **really** nice to have one...)

Unless you mean

```
width: 30px; height: 30px; /* A single line! */
```